# add date time from flat file name cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-streaming, impala

I started an EC2 cluster on amazon to install cloudera...I got it installed and configured and loaded some of the Wiki Page Views public snapshot into HDFS. The structure of the files are as such:

```
projectcode, pagename, pageviews, bytes
```

the files are named as such:

```
pagecounts-20090430-230000.gz
             date    time
```

when loading the data from HDFS to Impala, I do it as such:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE wikiPgvws
(
   project_code varchar(100),
   page_name varchar(1000),
   page_views int,
   page_bytes int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LOCATION '/user/hdfs';
```

one thing I missed is the date and time of each of the file. The dir:

```
/user/hdfs
```

contains multiple pagecount files associated with different dates and times. How can one pull that information and store it in a column when loading to impala?

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you are missing is the concept of partitions. If you define the table as partitioned, the data may be divided to different partitions based on the timestamp(in the name) of the file.  I'm able to work around it in `hive`, I hope you to do the needful(if any) for `impala` as there query syntax is the same.

For me, this problem is not possible to solve only using `hive`. So I mixed up bash with hive scripting and it works fine for me. This is how I wrapped it up :

1. Create table `wikiPgvws` with partition
2. Create table `wikiTmp` with same fields as `wikiPgvws` except for partitions
3. For each file
     **i.**  Load data into `wikiTmp`
     **ii.** `grep` timeStamp from fileName
     **iii.** Use `sed` to replace placeholders in a predefined `hql` script file to load the data to the actual table. Then run it.
4. Drop table `wikiTmp` & remove `tmp.hql`

The script is as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash

hive -e "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE wikiPgvws(
            project_code varchar(100),
            page_name varchar(1000),
            page_views int,
            page_bytes int
        )
        PARTITIONED BY(dts STRING)
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
        STORED AS TEXTFILE";

hive -e "CREATE TABLE wikiTmp(
            project_code varchar(100),
            page_name varchar(1000),
            page_views int,
            page_bytes int
        )
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
        STORED AS TEXTFILE"

for fileName in $(hadoop fs -ls /user/hdfs/bounty/pagecounts-*.txt | grep -Po '(?<=\s)(/user.*$)')
do
    echo "currentFile :$fileName"
    dst=$(echo $filename | grep -oE '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}')
    echo "currentStamp $dst"
    sed "s!sourceFile!'$fileName'!" t.hql > tmp.hql
    sed -i "s!targetPartition!$dst!" tmp.hql

    hive -f tmp.hql    

done

hive -e "DROP TABLE wikiTmp"
rm -f tmp.hql
```

The `hql` script consists of just two lines :

```
LOAD DATA INPATH sourceFile OVERWRITE INTO TABLE wikiTmp;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE wikiPgvws PARTITION (dts = 'targetPartition') SELECT w.* FROM wikiTmp w;
```

**Epilogue :**
Check, whether options equivalent to `hive -e` & `hive -f` are available in `impala`. Without them, this script is of no use to you. Again the grep commands to fetch the fileName & timeStamp need to be modified according to your table location and stamp pattern. It's just one a way to show how the job can be done, but couldn't able to find another one.

**Enhencement**
If everything works well, consider merging the first two DDLs into another script to make it look cleaner. Although, I'm not sure that `hql` script arguments can be used to define partition values, still you can have a look to replace `sed`.